# Move a web app project from eclipse to tomcat standalone

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, filter

Can you help please me with deploy an web app from eclipse to tomcat standalone
I have a web app run on context path "localhost:8080" and all request will go through a Main Filter like that

```
@WebFilter("/*")
public class MainFilter implements Filter {

    /**
     * Default constructor. 
     */
    public MainFilter() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see Filter#destroy()
     */
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    /**
     * @see Filter#doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain)
     */
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;

        String path = req.getRequestURI();
        request.setAttribute("uri", path);

        if( path.contains("/user")){
            if( path.contains("/post")){
                if( path.contains("/comment")){
                    req.getRequestDispatcher("/CommentServlet").forward(request, response);
                    return;
                }
                req.getRequestDispatcher("/PostServlet").forward(request, response);
                return;
            }
```

Could you tell me how to I can deploy it on tomcat with anything relate like create web.xml or config anything. Please help me here !

Comment: are you using maven?

Comment: @user1136403 I heard it before but I don't for sure. I you tomcat plugin on eclipse

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using maven, generate your projects war file and then go to your webapp directory which is under the tomcat folder. It might be something like that if you are using windows `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps` copy war file here. Then under the bin\ start your tomcat with startup.bat. This is old school method without maven. Take a look and research about maven.

Comment: yes ! I did that too but it just not go through the Filter ex: when I enter localhost:8080/blog/welcome.html it will run but if the url not match any file it will 404? can you tell me more details

Answer (score 0):

yes I'm done ! just post here for if other people look at

I was add a web.xml file like that

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>MainFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>MainFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>sleep-time-in-seconds</param-name>
        <param-value>10</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MainFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>welcome.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

And export my web to war file in webapps folder and change to ROOT.war
notice : my MainFilter in default package